# JS Express Get Paramters issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, routes

I'm fairly new to Express and Node JS. I have set up a server with a paginated table. It also has two views which show different columns (you can switch between the two of them via a button). The GET parameters for the pagination and views are stored in variables and when you click let's say the "next page" button, the href will contain the GET parameter "view" from the previous query as well as the new GET parameter for the next page.

Now I have also added a text input form for each column of the table. I now have issues passing the GET parameters from the previous query.

This is what an example form looks like. The variable allOptions stores the GET parameters from the previous query. Still, the resulting query at the router will only be: {sid: DGP}...

```
<form action="/idb?<% allOptions%>">
    <input size=3 type="text" id="sid" name="sid" value="DGP"><input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your server code ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Found the issue. I had to use hidden input fields in html... Thanks!